# SQL Server stored procedure to Update one database table from another database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am attempting to input the `SOPNUMBE` held in `Database2` into the `Invoice Number` in `Database1`. Nothing fancy but I keep hitting a wall. Any direction even if it is a book to read would be great.

```
Update Database1
Set Database1.dbo.TableA.[Invoice Number] = Database2.dbo.TableA.SOPNUMBE
Where Database1.dbo.TableA.[SO Number] = Database2.dbo.TableA.ORIGNUMB
```

Getting this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateInvoice, Line 18 [Batch
>   Start Line 7]
>   The multi-part identifier "Database2.dbo.TableA.ORIGNUMB" could not be
>   bound.

Comment: What database software are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Are both databases on the same server?

Comment: Yes Same server

Comment: From reading about that specific error, it would appear that SQL Server is having a hard time diciphering between the two database objects when calling that last portion in your Where Clause, maybe try aliasing your databases., also, your beginning Update statement, should be Update Database1.dbo.TableA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - I recreated your situation, and this query worked for me.

```
Update Database1.dbo.TableA
SET [Invoice Number] = b.SOPNUMBE
FROM Database1.dbo.TableA a
INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.TableA b ON a.[SO Number] = b.ORIGNUMB
```

Two things - one, you don't have Database2.dbo.TableA in a FROM clause or a JOIN clause - that's why it can't bind. Second, your UPDATE line - "Update Database1" doesn't qualify the table to update, but I assume that's a typo.

Comment: The changes allowed the code to execute without error I need to now research further on why it didn't perform the update.